# How do I target an html element in Angular from another sibling component (skip link)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, accessibility

I need to target a nested layout component's element from another sibling component. The desired target element is several layers deep within said component.  I Have a `Header` Component that is housing a Skip Link `<a></a>`.  Upon selecting the Skip Link I need to send `focus` to the aforementioned sibling component's `#main-content` element, which happens to be a `<div></div>`.  How can I achieve this?

I have tried creating a custom attribute directive.  I have tried targeting the element with `@ViewChild("main-content")`, I can't seem to get the target element to achieve focus, and thus show the border with style changes.  Any Advice is greatly appreciated.

**Header Component:**

```
...
<a [href]="skipLinkPath" class="skip-link" (click)="skipLink()" tabIndex="0">Skip to Main Content</a> 
...
```

**Header Component's TS:**

```
...
@ViewChild('#mainContent') mainContent: ElementRef;

...

skipLink() {
  console.log("click event called");
  console.log(this.mainContent);
  this.mainContent.nativeElement.focus();
} 
...
```

**Main Component:**

```
  <div class="content-display skip-link-focus" role="main"  id="main-content" #mainContent>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

Comment: is #mainContent part of headercomponent.html? if not @ViewChild('#mainContent') will not work

Comment: follow the link may help    https://medium.com/@pandukamuditha/angular-5-share-data-between-sibling-components-using-eventemitter-8ebb49b64a0a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a shared service to achive this

SharedService.ts
->

```
isFocus: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
```

Create a subject in shared service

Header Component

```
skipLink() {
  this.sharedService.isFocus.next(true);
}
```

Main Component
create a field

```
isFocus = false;
```

in on init method subscribe to service

```
this.sharedService.isFocus.subscribe(value => {
    this.isFocus = value;
});



  <div class="content-display skip-link-focus" role="main" [ngClass]={_focused: isFocus}  id="main-content" #mainContent>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

in css

```
._focused {
 //required css
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why the accepted answer is JavaScript based. This can all be achieved with no JS at all in a much simpler fashion and more robust way.

```
<a [href]="skipLinkPath" class="skip-link" (click)="skipLink()" tabIndex="0">Skip to Main Content</a>
```

Firstly the skip link shouldn't need a `tabindex`, if you needed to add that to make the link accessible have a quick look through your code for an issue as links are automatically added to the `focus` order.

The above could become:

```
<a [href]="#main-content" class="skip-link">Skip to Main Content</a>
```

Notice how I changed the `href` to match the id of your main content div.

```
  <div class="content-display" role="main"  id="main-content" #mainContent>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

The above will work without needing to handle the focus state yourself (if you want the main div to show that it is focused add `tabindex="0"` to it, but the above example will still skip the menu with the next tab stop being the first focusable item in your HTML).

### What about the URL change using an anchor?

Obviously the above adds a `#main-content` to your URL, I don't consider that an issue, but if you do, you could intercept the click and use the history API in the browser to stop the URL updating.

Although that may then seem like more work, you then have a functional skip link that works without JavaScript so that whatever no JavaScript fallback your site has is still accessible.

### final suggestion

```
  <div class="content-display" role="main"  id="main-content" #mainContent>
```

The above div looks like it could be changed to a `<main>` element to be more semantically correct as I am assuming you are using `HTML5`.